# asp.net MVC send parameters with handler.ashx to winforms c#

Tags: c#, ajax, winforms, model-view-controller, generic-handler

hi i have send string parameters  in my MVC view javascript button with ajax look like this;

```
**

$.ajax({
            url: 'myGenericHandler.ashx',
            type: 'GET',
            data: {'param1':'parameter','param2':'parameter2'},
            success: function (data) {
                console.log(data);
                alert("Success :" + data);
            },
            error: function (errorText) {
                alert("Warning");
            }
        });
```

**

when i take myGenericHandler.ashx param1 and param2 values.im sending to my WinForms C# myapp.exe on_load class which i  get values with httpwebrequest.create(../myGenericHandler.ashx) ......

myGenericHandler.ashx code
    public void ProcessRequest(HttpContext context)
            {

```
            try
            {

                string param1 = context.Request.QueryString["param1"];
                string param2 = context.Request.QueryString["param2"];



                context.Response.ContentType = "text/plain";
                context.Response.Write(param1+"-"+param2);
                context.Response.Flush();
                context.Response.Close();
                context.Response.End();    

            }
```

Winform C# myapp.exe form load

```
private void FDesktop_Load(object sender, EventArgs e) 
  {
HttpWebRequest req = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("http://localhost:xxxx/myGenericHandler.ashx");
WebResponse wr;
wr = req.GetResponse();       
StreamReader str = new StreamReader(wr.GetResponseStream());
string t = str.ReadToEnd();  
toolStripLabel1.Text = t; 
    }
```

myapp.exe start in MVC view

```
@{ 
    string path = @"C:\......\myapp.exe";
    Process p = Process.Start(path);
    p.WaitForExit();

}
```

My problem is in myGenericHandler.ashx load in MVC view param1 and param2 have values.But when i Proccess.Start(myapp.exe); myGenericHandler.ashx param1 and param 2 values are nulls.how can i start same time with myapp.exe myGenericHandler.ashx and view one.thank you.

Comment: It may be my eyes but should that be : data:{param1:'parameter',param2:'parameter2'},

Comment: please update your question by adding ashx handler code

Comment: i will add code  but firstly i want to say that ,i think  second request by myapp.exe to cause null values

Comment: can u suggest different idea for get from MVC string to winform C#?

Comment: i have edited  my solution